# Magento method to find: DEBUG (7): Error on save product purging: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: sql, database, debugging, magento

My log is full with this kind of errors and there are order problems sometimes. The log does not tell which program this error generates.

How can I find out generally which program this kind of errors generate, to search for text in all programs like "Error on save product" does not help ? Is there a database class/function I can debug for such errors and to find the problem program ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql` and set some properties to generate a log file.

```
class Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql extends Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql implements Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface
{
    // :
    protected $_debug = true;
    // :
    protected $_logAllQueries = true;
    // :
    protected $_logCallStack = true;
    // :
}
```

This way a log file named `var/debug/pdo_mysql.log` will be created and Magento will log each SQL statement (and exception), including stack traces of each operation.

Checking the stack traces easily allows you to identify which method call resulted in a given exception.

Comment: Thank you very much Jürgen for your answer, I go to try it and let you know. On your own it is impossible to find it all by yourself in Magento ..

Comment: Yes it works, but in a few seconds this file is already 250 MB, so after an hour / day, not to handle anymore. Is there software to handle such big files, I know Notepad++ goes to 1 Gb, but that is not enough, I find it a little bit creasy for a webshop so many sql .. ? Maybe I can build in somewhere only some sql to log ?

Comment: On cnet.com I found a .net program what can load easily a few Gb, Notepad++ can't ..

Comment: So I found where the error was generated in my case. I saw this errors in the system.log when I was saving a product. During saving I was building a piece of mysql log as described above. Than I search my error in this log and saw that extension MDN Erp tried to write twice a zero entry to table purges (before it was writing the product_id to this table succesfully, so maybe a loop problem). But if you don't know where to look e.g. I have also order problems (shipping_description empty sometimes with zero totals), this way of searching ends in nothing (too big mysql logfiles).

Comment: But how the text "save product purging" is composed I don't know, so you don't think at table purges, very unclear ... and even in the logs sentences are not complete, so you miss information too, Magento takes all your energy ..

Comment: Maybe is a solution to find my order problem to write a mysql trigger procedure for the order table ..

Comment: Easier than I thought, I changed in the Mysql.php where $_logAllQueries is used, that only sql statements are logged for order and quote tables, so I find the problem fast and the log stays small. BUT TRY THIS FIRST IN A TEST ENVIRONMENT, otherwise your live will break by some mistakes in programming ..